# How to use whereIn with <=?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Ok i have 6 of checkboxes in view:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" id="room1" value="1" />1
<input type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" id="room2" value="2" />2
<input type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" id="room3" value="3" />3
<input type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" id="room4" value="4" />4
<input type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" id="room5" value="5" />5
<input type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" id="room6" value="6" />6+
```

User can check all of them, but i have problem when user check for example first where value is 1 and last one where value is 6+. When user check that i want to get all records where value of room is 1 and value of `room >= 6`. Any suggestion how can i do that?

I tried this but this not working when user check last one.

```
  $value = 6;
    if (!in_array($value, $option)) {
          $query->whereIn('rooms',$option
         }
          else{
              $query->where('rooms','>=',$value);
         }
```

Comment: so if he selects 1,2 and 6+ he gets records where room value is either 1 or 2 or greater than or equal to 6?

Comment: no if he selects 1,2 and 6+ he will gets all records where room values is 1,2 and greater or equal to 6

Comment: rooms cannot be 1,2 and >= 6 at the same time. I guess you mean OR and not AND

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try if this works for you:

```
$value = 6;
if (!in_array($value, $option)) {
    $query->whereIn('rooms',$option);
}
else{
    $query->whereIn('rooms',$option)->orWhere('rooms', '>=', $value);
}
```

Comment: its not working properly, when i check 1,2,3 and 6+ i get all records ,and i dont need to get all records because i have some room with value 5,6

Comment: So you get the room with value 5 too with this query?

Comment: I just tried this and is working fine for me. I have records with values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, and my options array has 1,2,3,6 then it gave me records with values 1,2,3,6,7 (1,2,3 selected options and 6,7 i.e. >= 6)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$value = 6;
if (!in_array($value, $option)) {
    $query->whereIn('rooms', $option);
} else {
    $query->whereHas(
        'rooms',
        function($query) use ($value) {
            $query->where('rooms', '>=', $value);
        }
    );
}
```